# How can I increase the heap size of V8 which is compiled into MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, v8

I'm receiving warnings for V8 inside of MongoDB (v3) while running a map-reduce:

```
V8 GC epilogue heap stats -  total: 1477830040 exec: 2097152 used: 1474778864 limit: 1535115264
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to increase V8's heap size at runtime or recompile Mongo's V8 in such a way as to give me more room...

Comment: You might well note that V8 will no longer be the default JavaScript engine from MongoDB 3.2 and will instead revert to SpiderMonkey as in previous builds. Also rather than looking at tuning the JavaScript engine, you a probably better off describing the problem to be solved and the code currently implemented. Tuning the code that is processing should generally be preferable to altering the engine characteristics.